# Get Analytics data from someone's youtube channel using Youtube Analytics API

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to get some data about a specific youtube channel, NOT mine. Is that possible?

We can try it out online [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model?authuser=3) but they need `ids` param, and it's mentioned:

> Identifies the YouTube channel or content owner for which you are retrieving YouTube Analytics data. - To request data for a YouTube user, set the ids parameter value to channel==CHANNEL_ID, where CHANNEL_ID specifies the unique YouTube channel ID. - To request data for a YouTube CMS content owner, set the ids parameter value to contentOwner==OWNER_NAME, where OWNER_NAME is the CMS name of the content owner. (string)

I can't understand, can We get data from someone else channel, or only from our authenticated channel?

If no how to do that as [social blade](http://socialblade.com/youtube/) does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analytics data is private data.  In for your application to access private user data you must request that the user authenticate your application and grant you access to their data.

Yes you can get data from someone else's channel once they have authenticated your application.   You can **not** see data from a random users channel that would be their private data.

Note: In the event this is your google account with more then one channel you are referring to.   The youtube api is different then other google apis its channel based you will have to authenticate your application to each channel individually in order to see data on the different channels.   I suspect this is also true with YouTube analytics but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: thx for explanation, but how does social blade collect information (including ESTIMATED EARNINGS) about any random channel id? they don't require you any access. And I don't see nothing about earnings in YouTube Data API v3, they are only in  YouTube Analytics API and YouTube Reporting API

Comment: My guess they are just doing a calculation based upon Views, subscribers and videos.  All that information is publicly available from the API.   However IMO this really isn't true analytics and I doubt the "ESTIMATED EARNINGS" is very acurate.